# Recent attacks and vulnerabilities

Tags: attacks, vulnerability, vulnerability-markets

How can I be up to date and get news on recent attacks and vulnerabilities?

Is there any trusted source of information (websites, databases, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a few sites you can use - I'll link a few below:

#### News

[Krebs On Security](https://krebsonsecurity.com/)

[Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/category/news/)

[Erata Security](https://blog.erratasec.com/)

[Packet Storm](https://packetstormsecurity.com/)

[Hacker News](https://thehackernews.com/)

[We Live Security](https://www.welivesecurity.com/)

#### Vulnerabilities

[CVEDetails](https://www.cvedetails.com/)

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10)

EDIT: I'll update this list with more links shortly!

Updated the list to reflect @Nomad 's comment

Comment: Is there any sites where I can subscribe and get news about new attacks

Comment: This list requires at least a mention of CVEDetails and Packetstormsecurity. As per OP's comment: You can subscribe to RSS feeds on most of the sites mentioned.

Comment: @houssein most of these sites have RSS feeds, as Nomad pointed out. They also have mailing lists so you can get emails directly if you prefer that.